# Scheme - Eval an expression (or string) with binding a variable?

Tags: scheme

How can I do an eval with a variable bound?

That is, given either `'(+ 1 x)` or the string `"(+ 1 x)"`, I'd like to be able to bind `x` to an arbitrary val and do an eval.  How can I do that?

Comment: You make your own `eval` procedure since  `eval` in Scheme does not use the current lexical scope. Read [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) if you don't know how. What are you trying to do. Are you sure this is the real problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own function that evaluates simple expressions,

It should work like this on simple expressions

```
(my-eval '1 '()) ;=> 1
(my-eval 'x '((w . 6) (x . 3) (y . 7))) ;=> 3
```

and given a list it can evaluate each part with `MAP` then it will `APPLY` the `CAR` to the `CDR`.

To help you get started here's a skeleton

```
(define (my-eval exp env)
   (cond ((number? exp) exp)
         ((symbol? exp) .. ;; use ASSOC to look up EXP inside ENV
         ((list? exp) 
          (let ((exp^ ;; evaluate each subexpression recursively
                ))
            .. ;; use APPLY here
          ))
```

pass in an environment like this `((+ . ,+) (x . 5))